# Is it ok if I drop "have"?

Tags: subjunctives

> Mr. Trump called the leaking of information disgraceful comparing it to something that Nazi Germany would have done.

Could I change the above sentence to *Nazi Germany would do* dropping *have*?

Will it change the meaning?

Comment: Sure. It implies that Nazi Germany exists now.

Comment: "...would be something that Nazi Germany would do", implies that Nazi Germany still exists. *...would have done* reflects a past action.

Comment: You can get away with a general comment like _they would do_ since the suggestion does live in theory. If that regime were around (hypothetically), that is something they would do. They cannot do it, but they would do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you say "[some historical entity] *would do*" it either implies that entity still exists, or the *hypothetical* if the entity still existed.  So it's grammatical, but it has a more complex nuance that the past perfect.  Example:

> That's just the sort of thing my late grandmother would have said.
>
> That's just the sort of thing my late grandmother would say (if she was still alive today).